# Shortest way to get digit number from a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, numbers, int, digits

Let's say I have a number like 134658 and I want the 3rd digit (hundreds place) which is "6".

What's the shortest length code to get it in Objective-C?

This is my current code:

```
int theNumber = 204398234;
int theDigitPlace = 3;//hundreds place
int theDigit = (int)floorf((float)((10)*((((float)theNumber)/(pow(10, theDigitPlace)))-(floorf(((float)theNumber)/(pow(10, theDigitPlace)))))));

//Returns "2"
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the hundreth digit?

Comment: @Pavan Nope, I'm trying to get any given digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better solutions, but this one is slightly shorter:

```
int theNumber = 204398234;
int theDigitPlace = 3;//hundreds place
int theDigit = (theNumber/(int)(pow(10, theDigitPlace - 1))) % 10;
```

In your case, it divides the number by 100 to get 2043982 and then "extracts"
the last decimal digit with the "remainder operator" `%`.

*Remark:* The solution assumes that the result of `pow(10, theDigitPlace - 1)` is
exact. This works because `double` has about 16 significant decimal digits and `int` on iOS
is a 32-bit number and has at most 10 decimal digits.

Comment: +1 0o0o What you explained on how the solution works is quite clever. When i was trying to solve the problem I was able to obtain the last digit with the remainder operator, but I was overthinking how to adjust the digits. Just for curiosity sake, could you please explain what your thinking procecudure was like as you came up with the final solution. Again, Very cool.

Comment: @Pavan: You were almost there. If `x % 10` gives the last digit, then `(x / 10) % 10` gives the last but one digit, ...

Comment: Great, and then you cleverly adjusted x by doing 10 to the power of how much you want to displace x by. sweet! Thanks

Comment: I LOVE this!  But I am curious... dividing by 100, does this round it to an int or floor it to an int? Because if it rounds you will encounter errors and need to use the floor() function.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Dividing two integers always truncates the result.

Answer (score 1):

How about good old C?

```
int theNumber = 204398234;
char output[20];   //Create a string bigger than any number we might get.
sprintf(output, "%d", theNumber);
int theDigit = output[strlen(output)-4]-'0'; //index is zero-based.
```

That's really only 2 executable lines.

Yours is only 1 line, but that's a nasty, hard-to-understand expression you've got there, and uses very slow transcendental math.

Note: Fixed to take the 3rd digit from the right instead of the 3rd from the left. (Thanks @Maddy for catching my mistake)

Comment: Of course the performance depends on what `sprintf` does internally, it is hard to say if it is slower or faster than `pow` without benchmarking.

Comment: This is incorrect. It gives the 3rd digit from the left, not the hundreds digit.

Comment: @maddy, oops, you're right. Edited to correct my mistake.

Comment: This is a very clever solution :) Thanks! (I remember you from iphoneDevSDK like 5 years ago too haha)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that uses integer math, and a single line of code:

```
int theNumber = 204398234;
int result = (theNumber/100) % 10;
```

This is likely the fastest solution proposed yet.

It shifts the hundreds place down into the 1s place, then uses modulo arithmetic to get rid of everything but the lowest-order decimal digit.

Comment: I love this solution! (*Side note - this is base-10 only)

Comment: "this is base-10 only." Well, yeah. That is how the problem is stated. However, the same solution would be trivial in any base you wanted to use. Just divide the number by base^digit_number, and then take the result modulo(base).